# How to pass named pipe into CreateProcess (C++ Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, named

The hierarchy of my project is that I have 3 processes.

1. Main exe
2. Middle exe
3. Worker exe

Main exe will spawn middle exe using createprocess, from there middle exe will spawn worker exe using createprocess as well. Once worker exe is running middle exe terminates.

I would like to be able to pass the output data from worker exe back to main exe.

The way I think is best is to use a named pipe as worker exe's stdout.

In main exe I have this code:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, static_cast<PACL>(0), FALSE);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\MPipe"),
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_NOWAIT,
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
    1024 * 4,
    1024 * 4,
    0,
    &sa);

//CreateProcess() code here for middle exe

if (hPipe == NULL || hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to create pipe", NULL, MB_OK);
    }

int count = 0;
while (true) {
    if (!ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, 0)) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 5)
        break;
}
if (count > 5) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed...", NULL, MB_OK);
}
```

Then in middle exe I have

```
memset(&si, 0x00, sizeof(si));
memset(&pi, 0x00, sizeof(pi));
si.cb = sizeof(si);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
HANDLE hPipe;
BOOL keepGoing = TRUE;
while(keepGoing){
    hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\MPipe"),
        GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        &sa,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_BUSY) {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Pipe busy...", NULL, MB_OK);
            WaitNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\MPipe", 2000);
        }
        else {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to open pipe for writing", NULL, MB_OK);
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        keepGoing = FALSE;
    }
}

MessageBoxA(NULL, "Client pipe connected!", NULL, MB_OK);

SetHandleInformation(hPipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
si.hStdError = hPipe;
si.hStdOutput = hPipe;

processFlags = CREATE_SUSPENDED;

CreateProcessW(processPath, commandLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, processFlags, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

For some reason in Main exe it will output "Failed to establish connection..." But in my Middle exe it will output "Client connected!".

I can't figure out why the Middle exe appears to establish a connection but the Main exe doesn't recognize it when ConnectNamedPipe() is called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `GetLastError()` in your main.exe loop after `ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, 0)` to get the error code.

Comment: After Middle connects to Main, it is REMOVING the `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` flag from the pipe handle before then spawning Worker, thus Worker is not inheriting the pipe and cannot access it.  Since you are using a **named** pipe, it would be easiest to just have Middle pass the pipe name string to Worker via a command-line parameter without actually connecting to Main (or just hard-code the name directly in Worker), and then Worker can open a pipe connection directly to Main. If that is not an option, then you need to fix your broken inheritance in Middle.

Comment: IMHO, I would not use a **named** pipe. That is opening a backdoor that allows malicious processes to connect to Main.  I would suggest having Main create an **anonymous** pipe via `CreatePipe()` instead, and then let Middle inherit the writing end of at pipe when spawned, and then let Worker inherit that same pipe end when spawned. This way, Worker has a direct write-only pipe to Main without any backdoor openings for malicious processes to hijack.

Comment: `CreateProcess()` has an `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT` flag that can be used to let you pass a `STARTUPINFOEX` struct instead of a standard `STARTUPINFO` struct.  `STARTUPINFOEX` adds an additional `lpAttributeList` field that can be used to limit which handles are inherited by each process.  See [Programmatically controlling which handles are inherited by new processes in Win32](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the code for worker to handle it opening a pipe. And security isn't an issue at the moment as this is a personal project.

Comment: As far as fixing the middle exe's code would  SetHandleInformation(hPipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 1); fix that

Comment: You don't need the call to `SetHandleInformation` at all.  You've already set the handle as inheritable in the CreateFile call.  You also need to set `si.dwFlags` to `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` or `hStdError` and `hStdOutput` will be ignored.

Comment: I used GetLastError() from the server side to check what was going on.  Before the client connects I get error 536, the client connects server outputs error 535.  Then after that I get an error 232.  How do I check what these error numbers mean?

Comment: I found the errors in winerror.h. By the looks of it I assume 535 is a good thing meaning a client is connected.  But I'm confused why error 232 happens after that.  Could it be that the pipe handle for the worker.exe is no longer valid once middle.exe terminates?

Comment: You're using `PIPE_NOWAIT` **and** `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, so the behaviour is undefined.  `PIPE_NOWAIT` is the old way to do non-blocking I/O, `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` is the new way, you need to pick one or the other.  I strongly recommend you start with blocking I/O, i.e., use neither flag, and get it working that way first.  Depending on your circumstances, you might find that's all you need, but even if it isn't your life will be easier if you're sure you've eliminated all other bugs before introducing asynchronous or non-blocking I/O into the mix.

Comment: Will do. The client will output connected. Then two minutes later it'll output pipe busy. It's impossible to be executing the pipe busy segment of code a second time. I don't understand how that's occurring. Any idea?